# Asynchronous AJAX Calls in orderd manner

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

Hi firstly sorry for my bad English. I Already searched in SO. but i didn't get the exact answer i needed.
My issue is i need to synch the Ajax request. i know we can use the "**asynch : false** ".
but this will make browser locked. I have a folder tree(i am using "**tafel tree**" js) in my web. the tree nodes are generated at run-time. each time
user click a node it will send request to server and add the node to the tree.
but issue is if the page is refreshed by clicking ***f5*** then i need to load the tree structure that i already selected previously.
i implemented it using "**asynch : false** ". but this will makes browser too slow.

and here what i have

```
function loadPage() { 
/* some other codes are here*/
/* here i call an ajax for get the inside folder list in correct order.(i am usig     protoype)*/
    new Ajax.Request(ajaxGetInsideFolderIdsUrl,
    {
     parameters: {branchId: CurrentSelectfolderId},
     onSuccess:  function(res) {
            /* onSuccess i call another function*/
            var brs = res.responseText.split(","); // branch ids in correct order.
            syncFolder(brs)
    }
}

function syncFolder(brs){
for(var i= 0 ; i < brs.length; i ++){  
    var tempbranch = tree.getBranchById(brs[i].getId());              
    selectAfterChange( tempbranch) 
    /* 
     selectAfterChange function is used for selecting current branch. calling "tafle  tree" select() function in side it.
     i just created an copy of "select()","_openPopulate()" functions used in "tafle  tree" and modified it with "asynch : false ".and now its working fine.
*/  
}
}
function selectAfterChange(brs){
    brs.chk_select(); 
    /* for selecting the branch (created a copy of current "select()" function used in "tafle tree" js  
    and modified it with "asynch : false "and now its working fine.) */
    showList();// for listing items in side that folder (in another Ajax page). 
}
```

My problem is if a user opened a long branch. 
And then refresh the page it will take too much time to load because of synch Ajax call.
Taking too much time is not an big issue to me. but the browser is get locked until all the request executed.
is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Either you need to work with localstorage or make your backend work where it can return multiple nodes at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the tree library you're using, but in general, the way you'd solve this is to store the currently expanded path(s) in the browser (local storage, or cookies, or wherever), and when you refresh the page, load just the nodes that are visible.

Let's say that the user is currently looking at path one/two/three/four. You save that path somewhere, and then when the page loads again, you create a queue of paths to request from the back end, by splitting the path, and appending the components of the path one by one:

```
["one", "one/two", "one/two/three"]
```

You then send the AJAX request for "one", and when you get the result back, update that node in the tree, and send a request for "one/two". When that request returns, update the tree, and send the request for "one/two/three".

Depending on your design, you can then start filling in the rest of the tree with more async requests...

Comment: Thank you sir for ur replay. Now what i am doing is i get the id from hash in url (eg:- url#fId=5) and then i call loadPage() function and  just send this id ( please see the first ajax call in my question.).